# Git - avoid committing all projects to sync one project

Tags: git, github

I have just started using Github.

We are a team of two working on two projects from the Github repo.

> **Problem :** While syncing one project, The git wants me to commit changes in all the repo projects, including those projects on which I
>   have not worked  nor made any changes. The git shows that almost all
>   files from all projects needs to be committed in order to solve the branch
>   diverged issue.

[image]

How can I resolve this issue , as I'm not able to push my commits.

We face this issue multiple times.

Please help !!

EDIT:
Both of us/team members are using Windows and one other person who works on some other projects in repo uses mac os.

Comment: What do the diffs show before you commit the merge?

Comment: Did this happen while merging? If so, then did you commit all your changes before merging?

Comment: @pratZ This happened after merging and committing the merge. Now, it shows  changes in all the repo projects, including those projects on which I have not worked nor made any changes.

Comment: @scipilot I did not check the diff. I use egit in eclipse, It showed merger conflicts in my project that I resolved

Answer (score 0):

This is called problem of line ending. Since you are using windows and other developer is using Linux/MacOS,

> Every time you press return on your keyboard you're actually inserting
>   an invisible character called a line ending. Historically, different
>   operating systems have handled line endings differently.

solution :

```
    git config --global core.autocrlf input
    # Configure Git on OS X or Linux to properly handle line endings

    git config --global core.autocrlf true
    # Configure Git on Windows to properly handle line endings
```

Refer- [help.github.com](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/#platform-all)

Comment: Both of us/team members are using Windows and one other person who works on some other projects in repo uses mac os.

Comment: I'm pretty sure thats the case. I had similar situation. Also not sure how powershell deals with line endings.

Comment: I have run the git config command. The github help link tells to Refreshing a repository after changing line endings- "The best way to automatically configure your repository's line endings is to first backup your files with Git, delete every file in your repository (except the .git directory), and then restore the files all at once." Will this delete my code from local or master ??

Comment: That apporach is good if you don't care about commit history. (you won't be able to 'blame' on existing commit. ) This solution is ideal as  your team size is tiny.  Do it.

Comment: Will this affect other projects ? The repo has large no. of projects used by other teams . Please help

Comment: Check per repository setting on that github link. Its safe

Comment: Hi, If your problem has solved please do the courtesy of marking the question as solved and accept answer :)

Answer (score 0):

In your `gitconfig` file, (wherever those settings are for your system, see the docs) you can have `safecrlf = true' and this should avoid the issue.

However, there is some risk.

The manual says this:

```
   core.safecrlf
       If true, makes Git check if converting CRLF is reversible when end-of-line conversion is
       active. Git will verify if a command modifies a file in the work tree either directly or
       indirectly. For example, committing a file followed by checking out the same file should
       yield the original file in the work tree. If this is not the case for the current setting
       of core.autocrlf, Git will reject the file. The variable can be set to "warn", in which
       case Git will only warn about an irreversible conversion but continue the operation.

       CRLF conversion bears a slight chance of corrupting data. When it is enabled, Git will
       convert CRLF to LF during commit and LF to CRLF during checkout. A file that contains a
       mixture of LF and CRLF before the commit cannot be recreated by Git. For text files this
       is the right thing to do: it corrects line endings such that we have only LF line endings
       in the repository. But for binary files that are accidentally classified as text the
       conversion can corrupt data.

       If you recognize such corruption early you can easily fix it by setting the conversion
       type explicitly in .gitattributes. Right after committing you still have the original
       file in your work tree and this file is not yet corrupted. You can explicitly tell Git
       that this file is binary and Git will handle the file appropriately.

       Unfortunately, the desired effect of cleaning up text files with mixed line endings and
       the undesired effect of corrupting binary files cannot be distinguished. In both cases
       CRLFs are removed in an irreversible way. For text files this is the right thing to do
       because CRLFs are line endings, while for binary files converting CRLFs corrupts data.

       Note, this safety check does not mean that a checkout will generate a file identical to
       the original file for a different setting of core.eol and core.autocrlf, but only for the
       current one. For example, a text file with LF would be accepted with core.eol=lf and
       could later be checked out with core.eol=crlf, in which case the resulting file would
       contain CRLF, although the original file contained LF. However, in both work trees the
       line endings would be consistent, that is either all LF or all CRLF, but never mixed. A
       file with mixed line endings would be reported by the core.safecrlf mechanism.

   core.autocrlf
       Setting this variable to "true" is almost the same as setting the text attribute to
       "auto" on all files except that text files are not guaranteed to be normalized: files
       that contain CRLF in the repository will not be touched. Use this setting if you want to
       have CRLF line endings in your working directory even though the repository does not have
       normalized line endings. This variable can be set to input, in which case no output
       conversion is performed.
```

Comment: I have added `safecrlf = true' still the same issue